# Argument of type Void is incompatible pthread c++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I want the Run function to run its own thread, but it shows an error, how to make it compatible with each other

> Error : argument of type "void *(cMain::*)(void *arg)" is incompatible
> with parameter of type "void *(__cdecl *)(void *)"

cMain.h

```
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#include <pthread.h>

using std::string;
class cMain
{ 
public:
    cMain();
    ~cMain();

public:
    wxListView *Listview1 = nullptr;
    
    void *Run(void *arg);
    int main();
};
```

cMain.cpp

```
void * cMain::Run(void *arg)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        i += 1;
        Listview1->SetItem(0, 0, std::to_string(i));

        Sleep(200);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}

int cMain::main()
{
    pthread_t my_thread;

    int ret;

    ret = pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &Run, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error: pthread_create() failed", L"AA", MB_OK);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

> error code : ret = pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &Run, NULL);

Comment: You tagged your question with `c`. In the title you have `c++`. You use C-specific linux thread interface - `pthread_*`. Your code is in C++. In C++ use C++ - use `std::thread`. So you write in C or in C++? `argument of type "void (cMain::)(void *arg)" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *(__cdecl *)(void *)"` and research what is a function member and what is a pointer to member function and how to use it. You can't pass a pointer to class member function to `pthread`. You have to pass `void(void*)` function.

Comment: You can pass an object pointer as the last argument to pthread_create().  Your thread function, (free or static), could then retrieve its parameter, cast to object class and then call the method on it.

Comment: You are trying to use a pointer to a member function. pthread expects a pointer to a standalone function.

Answer (score 2):

The typical solution is to do this:

```
class cMain
{ 
public:
    cMain();
    ~cMain();

public:
    wxListView *Listview1 = nullptr;
    
    void *Run();
    static void *cRun(void *p) {
      return reinterpret_cast<cMain*>(p)->Run();
    }
...
};

int cMain::main()
{
    pthread_t my_thread;
    int ret;

    ret = pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &cRun, this);
    ...
```

That is: create a *static* function in your class, whose sole purpose is to convert the `void*` pointer into the instance of your class, so other functions on that instance can be invoked.